# How to implement an unbiased random method for signed integers within a range?

Tags: random, rust

I've been creating a slim library for random number generation, and I've been struggling with generating signed integers within a range.

Unsigned integers are easy, I've implemented Lemire's debiased integer multiplication method. However, it does not extend easily to signed integers:

```rust
impl<R: Rng> RandomRange<R> for u64 {
    fn random_range<B: RangeBounds<Self>>(r: &mut R, bounds: B) -> Self {
        const BITS: u128 = core::mem::size_of::<u64>() as u128 * 8;
        let lower = match bounds.start_bound() {
            Bound::Included(lower) => *lower,
            Bound::Excluded(lower) => lower.saturating_add(1),
            Bound::Unbounded => <u64>::MIN,
        };
        let upper = match bounds.end_bound() {
            Bound::Included(upper) => upper.saturating_sub(lower).saturating_add(1),
            Bound::Excluded(upper) => upper.saturating_sub(lower),
            Bound::Unbounded => <u64>::MAX,
        };
        let mut value = Self::random(r);
        let mut m = (upper as u128).wrapping_mul(value as u128);
        if (m as u64) < upper {
            let t = (!upper + 1) % upper;
            while (m as u64) < t {
                value = Self::random(r);
                m = (upper as u128).wrapping_mul(value as u128);
            }
        }
        (m >> BITS) as u64 + lower
    }
}
```

How would I implement mostly debiased random number generation within a min/max range for signed integers?

Comment: For those not wanting to _implement_ it, see also [How to generate a random Rust integer in a range without introducing bias?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52454677/155423).

Comment: See also my section: [`RNDINTRANGE`](https://peteroupc.github.io/randomfunc.html#RNDINTRANGE_Random_Integers_in_N_M).

Comment: It's not clear what you find difficult about converting the algorithm to signed numbers. You know the width of the range and the start of the range. Can you not generate an unsigned range with the same width, then shift the resulting value by the start?

Comment: @Shepmaster: Wait yeah, you're right... Gimme a bit, I'll try to answer this myself for clarity.

Comment: i am now struggling with the whole i32-u32 conversion thing, ugh.

Comment: nvm i have no clue what i am doing

Comment: nvm i just refactored the code to be simpler and it just worked lmao

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I got it to work. I use a wrapping add around `<$type>::MAX / 2 + 1` to map the range of a signed integer to an unsigned integer.

```rust
fn random_range<B: RangeBounds<Self>>(r: &mut R, bounds: B) -> Self {
    const SIGNED_MAPPING: u64 = <u64>::MAX / 2 + 1;
    let lower = match bounds.start_bound() {
        Bound::Included(lower) => *lower,
        Bound::Excluded(lower) => lower.saturating_add(1),
        Bound::Unbounded => <i64>::MIN
    };
    let upper = match bounds.end_bound() {
        Bound::Included(upper) => *upper,
        Bound::Excluded(upper) => upper.saturating_sub(1),
        Bound::Unbounded => <i64>::MAX,
    };
    let lower = (lower as u64).wrapping_add(SIGNED_MAPPING);
    let upper = (upper as u64).wrapping_add(SIGNED_MAPPING);
    assert!(upper >= lower, "{} >= {}", upper, lower);
    <u64>::random_range(r, lower..=upper).wrapping_add(SIGNED_MAPPING) as i64
}
```